# Improper printing of uint8_t variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a small integer value (less than 10) to a uint8_t variable. I do it like this

```
uint8_t myID = atoi(argv[5]);
```

However when I do this

```
std::cout << "My ID is "<< myID <<std::endl;
```

It prints some non-alphanumeric character. There is no issue when myID is of type int. I tried casting explicitly by doing

```
uint8_t myID = (uint8_t)atoi(argv[5]);
```

But the results are the same. Could anyone explain why this is the case and if there is any possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint8_t` is not a separate data type. On systems that provide it the actual type is aliased to some standard data type, most commonly, an `unsigned char`.

Operator `<<` provides an overload that takes `unsigned char`, and prints it as a character. When you are printing your `uint8_t` variable as an `int`, cast it to an `int` for printing:

```
std::cout << "My ID is "<< int(myID) <<std::endl;
//                         ^^^^^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RySIHa)

Answer (score 2):

That's because on your platform, `uint8_t` is a `typedef` for an `unsigned char`.

And the ostream overloaded `<<` for an `unsigned char` outputs a character, rather than a number, since the clever C++ folk thought that to be sensible. It normally is.

You can fix this by casting to an `int`, which will always be able to accept an `uint8_t` value.

(Note that prior to C++14, a `char` could be a 1's complement or signed magnitude 8 bit signed type, so it could be different to uint8_t).

Comment: Thanks. So is there any other way of displaying the number?